# How do I extract the first characters from files names?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to email every file from a Google Drive folder that starts with the same name to the same person.

I have a list of emails and a list of words related to them - so

- 'person1@mail.com' works at 'Unit 1'
- 'person2@mail.com' at 'Building 2'
- 'person3@mail.com' at 'Department ABC'
- and so on.

Note that the units' names have different sizes, and they don't follow a pattern. I have a list of files on Drive with names such as

- 'Unit 1 - FileA.pdf'
- 'Building 2 - FilesMarch.pdf'
- 'Building 2 - FileB.pdf'
- and so on.

Once again, the rest of the files don't follow a pattern either, and some units have 1 file, while some others have up to 5.

So I have to email all files that start with, say, 'unit 1' to Person1@gmail, but I can't seem to figure how to extract the first letters of the files. Below I show you how I solved the problem with only one file with a fixed name per email, with the units' names on column B and the emails on column C:

```
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID goes here')
  var sheet = ws.getSheetByName('Sheetname goes here')  

  var message = 'messagegoeshere'
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder ID')

    for (var i = 2 ; i < 500 ; ++i) {
  var name = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue()
  var recipient = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue()

  //some units have more than one recipient     
  if (sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue() != '') {
  var recipient = recipient + ', ' + sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue()
  }


  var attach = files.getFilesByName(name + '.PDF')
  var title = 'title'
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, title, message, {attachments: [attach.next()]})
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the FileIterator for the folder:

```
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder ID').getFiles();
```

and then iterate over it in a while loop

```
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next(); 
  // work with the file 
}
```

For better performance, don't call `getValue` in a long loop: get all the values you need from a sheet before entering the loop.

To check whether a file name begins with a given string, one can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) since the convenient [startsWith method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) is not yet supported by Apps Script. Here is how it  can look like.

```
function answer() {
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID goes here')
  var sheet = ws.getSheetByName('Sheetname goes here')  
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 500, 2).getValues();   // all we need
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(' Id here ').getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var name = file.getName();
    var recipients = [];             // using an array to collect recipients
    for (var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {
      var re = new RegExp('^' + data[i][0]);    // check for data[i][0] at the beginning
      if (re.test(name)) {
        recipients.push(data[i][1]);
      }
    }
    if (recipients.length > 0) {
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipients.join(', '), 'My Subject', 'My Message', {attachments: [file]});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm really glad you answered! Thanks a lot!
I'm still new to Google Script (and Java), so it's especially good to see how someone with more experience would handle this problem.

Comment: No problem. A couple of points: Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript -- not on Java which is a very different language.  Also, if a Stack Exchange answer solves your problem, you may want to record this fact by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Comment: There's something not quite working. I noticed there's an 's' missing in the last line (recipientS). But still, the code identifies that the array 'recipients' isn't blank, but there's no email address in it.

Comment: Indeed, there was another error: I placed the email-sending line inside the for loop. Fixed now. If it doesn't work for you, put Logger.log(recipients) after MailApp, to see what exactly is in the array.

Comment: It works, thanks! I noticed the "for (var i = 2; i < data.length; i++)"  had to be slightly changed to " for (var i = 0; i < (0.5 * data.length); i++) " but other than that, it's perfect! I'm really glad, thank you!